# How to find and retrieve nearby latitude and longitude values stored in a Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing an Android app where users sign up and store their current location on a Firebase database. I'm looking to display the location of nearby users on a map by taking the latitude and longitude of a user and using it to look through the firebase database and find users who live nearby (within a certain radius).

I'm currently trying to order the latitudes and longitudes in the database, store them, and somehow loop through them to find the ones near to the user's location. But that seems like a very inefficient way to go about this as the database can become quite big with more and more users.

Is there any way I can find out how many latitudes and longitudes fall within a certain radius centered around a user's current location?

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java